# my php code cant create directory in host

Tags: php, mysql, directory

im using this php code to create backup of all my MYSQL databases.
but it sends this error : cant create directory

```
<?php
..
..
..
..

        if (mysql_select_db($db)) print "Selected [$db]\n";
        else die("Failed to select db [$db]");
        foreach (array("schema","data") as $pass){
            $sql = mysql_query("show tables");
            $day = date("l");
            if ($pass=="schema") $dir = "/$backup_dir/$db/schema";
            else $dir =  "/$backup_dir/$db/$day";
            if (!file_exists($dir)) system("mkdir -p $dir");
            if (!file_exists($dir)) die("Couldn't Create $dir");
            if ($pass=="data"){
                $latest = ( /$backup_dir/$db/latest"; )
                unlink($latest);
                system("/bin/ln -s \"$dir\" \"$latest\"");
            }            
            cleanup($dir);
            if ($sql) while ($s = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) {
                if (!isset($s["Tables_in_{$db}"])) {
                    print "no result";
                    print_r($sql);
                    die();
                }

..
..
..

?>
```

with below code , i could create directory in my host:

```
<?php
$structure = './depth1/depth2/depth3/';
if (!mkdir($structure, 0777, true)) {
    die('Failed to create folders...');
}
?>
```

is there any way to combine these codes or any other suggestion to solve this issue?

regards :)

Comment: `system("mkdir -p $dir 777")`

Comment: you are working with linux os?

Comment: thanks for your feedback . my os is Windows 2012 r2 (if it helps)

Answer (score 0):

I understand your problem so, that you just cant create a Folder on your Webserver? So you mostly dont have any rights on that folder, or better said. The webserver-user doesnt have any.

If you are using a Webserver like apache2 on Linux, you have to give the user www-data rights on the parent folder of your Backup folder.

The linux Command: 
`chown -R www-data:www-data <your Folder>`

Comment: Dear lino, thanks for your answer. but the problem is not in Write Permissions . the folder has Full (read/Write) permission. as i mentioned second code create that path without problem./ by the way im using windows server 2012

Comment: @SaeedMohammadi OH ok then, have you tried creating just a file? or maybe is the path incorrect, because from where you open the File it could be that the Paths dont work correctly anymore :)

Comment: Dear lino, thanks for your comment./ yes i did. i create that path by my self, but it didnt helped.../

Comment: @SaeedMohammadi ok then i cant help you :) sorry if I confused you